# opengl indexed drawing issue

Tags: c++, opengl

i'm trying to render a sphere with opengl (3.0). the algorithm below computes the vertices and the according indices. all in all it works quite well, however, there seem to be a glitch in the matrix, cause i get an ugly cone inside the sphere.

[image]

```
vertices.resize(rings * segments * 3);
colors.resize(rings * segments * 3);
indices.resize(6 * rings * segments);

auto v = vertices.begin();
auto c = colors.begin();
auto i = indices.begin();

auto dTheta = M_PI / (f32)rings;
auto dPhi   = 2 * M_PI / (f32)segments;

for ( u32 ring = 0; ring < rings; ++ring ) {
    auto r0 = radius * sinf(ring * dTheta);
    auto y0 = radius * cosf(ring * dTheta);
    for ( u32 segment = 0; segment < segments; ++segment ) {
        auto x0 = r0 * sinf(segment * dPhi);
        auto z0 = r0 * cosf(segment * dPhi);

        *v++ = x0;  *c++ = color.r;
        *v++ = y0;  *c++ = color.g;
        *v++ = z0;  *c++ = color.b;

        if (ring < rings) {
            *i++ = ( (ring  ) * segments ) + segment;
            *i++ = ( (ring+1) * segments ) + segment;
            *i++ = ( (ring+1) * segments ) + segment + 1;
            *i++ = ( (ring+1) * segments ) + segment + 1;
            *i++ = ( (ring  ) * segments ) + segment + 1;
            *i++ = ( (ring  ) * segments ) + segment;
        }
    }
}
```

any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: I think it should be `if (ring+1 < rings) {`, shouldn't it? If that's not the problem then you should post the rendering code.

Comment: yep, you're right :) ... don't ever trust code you take from internet ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*i++ = ( (ring+1) * segments ) + segment + 1;
*i++ = ( (ring+1) * segments ) + segment + 1;
*i++ = ( (ring  ) * segments ) + segment + 1;
```

What index do you compute if `segment` is equal to `segments - 1`? Yes, you get an index from the *next* segment.

And if there *is* no next segment? Then you get an index outside of your list of points.

Your segment increment needs to wrap around to 0:

```
*i++ = ( (ring+1) * segments ) + (segment + 1) % segments;
*i++ = ( (ring+1) * segments ) + (segment + 1) % segments;
*i++ = ( (ring  ) * segments ) + (segment + 1) % segments;
```

Also, consider what happens if `ring` is equal to `rings - 1`. Same problem, but you need a different solution. Your `if` statement is wrong. It should be:

```
if((ring + 1) < rings)
```

Comment: awesome, got the first figured out myself ... second worked as well nicely.

Comment: bah, now there's a hole on the lower end of the sphere :/

Comment: nevermind, got that as well. the for loop goes to `ring <= rings` so that the angle goes from zero to Pi. the vectors have to be altered to occupy space for `ring+1` entries.